# How to update user's scores every hour to my Leaderboard using Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection "scores" which includes some data in each documents for each user:-

- userId
- score
- avatarPath for firebase storage
- username

I can so use

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
db.collections("scores").whereGreaterThan(field = "score", value = 0).orderBy("score", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(100)
```

As we can see, I want the 100 best users' scores to display them in my Leaderboard, with the avatarPath and usernames.
**The problem is that I want the users's scores to update every hour, I don't want them to be updated immediatly to reduce Firestore cost.**

I heard about Cloud Functions, but I don't know if in my use case it's necessary because I store my score in SharedPreferences and in the Cloud Functions Index.js file(where we write Cloud functions in Android Studio) and I think we can't retrieve SharedPreferences value in this file.

I don't know if I need to create another collection called "leaderboard" and each field of the document contains `userId: score` and then query the 100 best scores and update the leaderboard document.I'm a bit lost in all this.

Comment: You can try WorkManager with PeriodicWorkRequest.

Comment: We can use WorkManager along with Firestore? I didn't know it I'll try.